# LU- decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

> Find an LU-decomposition of the coefficient matrix and solve the system $$\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 4 & 3\\ -1 & -1 & 3 \\ 2 & 9 & 8 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 8 \\ 12 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

I tried to find $L$ (on the right) and $U$ (on the left).

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ -1 & -1 & 3 \\ 2 & 9 & 8 \end{pmatrix} \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;\;\;\;\begin{pmatrix} \cdot & 0 & 0\\ 1 & \cdot & 0 \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \end{pmatrix}$

$\sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 3 & 6 \\ 2 & 9 & 8 \end{pmatrix} \;\;\;\;\;\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;\;\begin{pmatrix} \cdot & 0 & 0\\ 1 & \cdot & 0 \\ 2 & \cdot & \cdot \end{pmatrix}$

$\sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 3 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \;\;\;\;\;\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;\;\begin{pmatrix} \cdot & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & \cdot & \cdot \end{pmatrix}$

$\sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \;\;\;\;\;\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;\;\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & \cdot \end{pmatrix}$

$\sim \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = U \; \; \;\; \; \; \; \; \;\;\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & ? \end{pmatrix} = L$

Have I done it right? And should there be $1$ or $0$ where "?" is?

Comment: First line, why isn't $\textbf{L}$ an identity matrix?

Comment: I just used the same method as in my textbook where they put dots for unknown entries of L and then filled it in. But there should be a $1$ where the question mark is then?

Comment: Must have done something wrong since I then get 

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ \frac{4}{3} \\ \frac{8}{3} \end{pmatrix} $$

and $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=\frac{8}{3}$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the method is in your texbook, so I just show my way(I believe it's a clear procedure.)

If I want to do LU decomposition, then I would turn $\textbf{A}$ into a **reduced row echelon form** by row operation.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 3\\
-1 & -1 & 3\\
2 & 9 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&3\\
-1&-1&3\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
-2&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&3\\
0&3&6\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
-2&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&3\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
\frac{-7}{3}&\frac{-1}{3}&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here we have turned $Ax=I$ into $Ux=L'$, so we find $L=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
\frac{-7}{3}&\frac{-1}{3}&1\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&3&0\\
2&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Finally, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 3\\
-1 & 1 & 3\\
2 & 9 & 8
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&3&0\\
2&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&3\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}=LU$$

For your last comment,$$
Ux=\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&3\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}x=L'\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
8\\
12\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
\frac{-7}{3}&\frac{-1}{3}&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
8\\
12\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
4\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Got the right answer now, thanks!